# How to prove in general that AB = BA = I, with A lower triangular and B it's inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Let A be an n x n lower-triangular matrix with all ones a zero entries.
Let B be its inverse, given in second matrix as general notation.
Prove that AB=BA=I.

Intuitively this really makes sense, but how should I go about it formally?
$b_{ij} =
\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    1 & \quad \textrm{if } i=j \\
    -1 & \quad \textrm{if } i=j+1 \\
    0                 & \quad \textrm{else}
  \end{array}
\right.$

$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&.&.&.&0\\
1&1&0&.&.&.&0\\
1&1&1&.&.&.&0\\
1&1&1&.&.&.&0\\
.&1&1&.&.&.&0\\
.&.&.&.&.&1&0\\
1&.&.&.&1&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

$B=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&.&.&.&0\\
-1&1&0&.&.&.&0\\
0&-1&1&.&.&.&0\\
0&0&-1&.&.&.&0\\
.&0&0&.&1&.&0\\
.&.&.&.&-1&1&0\\
0&.&.&.&0&-1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: What exactly is the question? If $B$ is the inverse of $A$, then by definition $AB=I=BA$.

Comment: I think it is more to show that this actually holds for this specific matrix without saying that it is so by definition.

Comment: hint: let $\eta$ be the matrix with $1$ at subdiagonal and $0$ elsewhere. What is $\eta^2, \eta^3,\ldots$. Express $A,B$ in terms of $\eta^k$ and use the fact $\eta^n = 0$.

Comment: I see, then you can compute $$(AB)(k,\ell)= \sum_{j=1}^n A(k,j) B(j, \ell).$$ Now if $\ell\neq n$, we get that $B(j, \ell)$ vanishes except for $j\in \{\ell, \ell +1\}$, thus, we get $$(AB)(k,\ell)= A(k,\ell) B(\ell, \ell) + A(k,\ell+1) B(\ell+1,\ell).$$ Then you can insert the definitions and check whether this gives the correct answer.

Comment: @user773674 $\eta$ has all entries one. so $A = I_n + \eta + \eta^2 + \cdots + \eta^{n-1}$ and $B = I_n - \eta$. so $AB = I_n - \eta^n = I_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the right direction, but a lower triangular matrix can be considered a "running sum matrix". Suppose we have any vector
$$x = \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}$$
Then
$$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}x_0 \\ x_1+x_0 \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=0}^n(x_i)\end{bmatrix}$$
And what is the inverse of a running sum? some kind of backwards difference matrix, right?

Comment: Would one get then $Bx= \begin{pmatrix} x_1-x_0\\.\\.\\.\\x_n - x_{n-1}\\x_n \end{pmatrix}$ But then this is also $x_0 \begin{pmatrix} -1\\1\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0   
 \end{pmatrix}$  + $x_1 \begin{pmatrix} 1\\-1\\0\\.\\.\\.\\0 \end{pmatrix} + ... + $ Now the first columns shouldt be there

Comment: I see, I mixed up some terms, it should be some kind of causal differentiation, so like $x_i - x_{i-1}$, with $x_{-1} = 0$. Therefore one would get $Bx = \begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ x_1 - x_0 \\ \vdots \\ x_n - x_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Okay that's very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_{i,\cdot}$ be the i-th row of $A$ with entries $a_{ij}$ and $b_{\cdot,j }$ be the j-th column of $B$ with entries $b_{ij}$. Clearly
$$a_{ij} = \begin{cases}1&, j \leq i \\\ 0&, \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
By your definition
$$
b_{ij} = \begin{cases}1&, i = j \\\ -1 &,i=j+1 \\\ 0&, \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $c_{ij}$ be the entries of the product $AB$. Clearly $c_{in} = \delta_{in}$. Furthermore for $j < n$ we have
$$
c_{ij} = \langle a_{i,\cdot}, b_{\cdot, j} \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj} = a_{ij} b_{jj} + a_{i, j+1} b_{j+1, j} = a_{ij} - a_{i, j+1}
$$
where the step from the sum expression follows since all other $b$s are zero.
Can you complete the proof that this is equal to $\delta_{ij}$ from here (where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta)?

EDIT:

Note that we can consider two cases for $c_{ij}$: the one where $i = j$ and the one where $i \neq j$.

Let $i=j$, then $a_{i,j+1} = a_{j,j+1}$ and since $j+1 \nleq j$ this is "in the lower branch of $a_{ij}$" and thus $0$. This means for $i=j$ we have $c_{ij} = a_{ij} - 0 = a_{jj} = 1$.

Now we'll consider the case $i \neq j$ which further splits into $i<j$ and $i>j$.
Let $i < j$. Surely $i < j+1$ and thus our expression for $c_{ij}$ evaluates to $0$ since both of our $a$'s "land in the second branch" of our definition for $a_{ij}$.
If instead $i > j$, then in particular $j \leq i$ and thus $a_{ij} = 1$. Furthermore we have the strict inequality and thus we also have $j+1 < i$ (if this is confusing consider some example: $4 < 5$, but $4+1 \leq 5$) and so $a_{i,j+1} = 1$. So $c_{ij} = 1 - 1 = 0$.

In total this means for $i=j$ we have $c_{ij} = 1$ and for $i \neq j$ we have $c_{ij}=0$, so for arbitrary $i,j$ we get
$$
c_{ij} = \delta_{ij},
$$
which means
$$
AB=I_n
$$
and so $B$ is the inverse of $A$.

Comment: You probably want to consider the case $j=n$ separately.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll edit it

Comment: Yes, sorry I mixed this up. I fixed it now and added the rest of the solution as an edit.

Comment: Another comment: you mentioned that you see that $Ab_i = e_i$, at this point you've actually proven that $B$ is the inverse of $A$ (since you can write $I$ and $B$ as block matrices; so if you directly see this equality, there is no need to actually do all this algebra I've did in my answer. Most people would probably just say "oh it's obvious that this is the inverse" rather than do all this calculation. And since you mentioned that you "don't think this is possible with a standard proof of assuming $n$ and proving $n+1$": I wouldn't call this standard proof.

Comment: What you mean is called proof by induction and yes, it can often be used and make some otherwise very hard proofs quite simple but don't restrict yourself to this kind of argument. I'll add another answer with a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n$ be the $(n \times n)$-Matrix with entries $a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 &, j\leq i \\\ 0 &,\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and $B_n$ the corresponding matrix $B$ of your definition.
For $n=1$ we have $A_1 = B_1 = I_1$ and thus trivially $B_1 = A_1^{-1}$.

Now assume that $B_n = A_n^{-1}$. Write $A_{n+1}$ and $B_{n+1}$ as block-matrices as follows:
$$
A_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0_{1, n} \\\ 1_{n, 1} & A_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0_{1, n} \\\ -e_{1} & B_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $e_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n,1}$.
Then
$$
A_{n+1} B_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\cdot 1 - 0_{1,n} e_1 & 1 \cdot 0_{1, n} + 0_{1,n} B_n \\\ 1 \cdot 1_{n,1} - A_n e_{1} & 1_{n,1} 0_{1,n} + A_n B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0_{1, n} \\\ 1_{n,1} - a_{1,\cdot} & 1_{n,1} 0_{1,n} + A_n B_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0_{1, n} \\\ 0_{n,1} & I_n \end{pmatrix} = I_{n+1}
$$
where we've used our assumption that $A_n B_n = I_n$. By the principle of induction we've shown that $B_n = A^{-1}_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.